Expectation of real number exponentiated by Poisson process
Consider a Poisson process $N_t$ with intensity $\lambda>0$ and let $x$ be a real-valued number. In principle, from the properties of the Poisson distribution, we have:
$$\mathbb{E}(x^{N_t})=e^{\lambda t(x-1)}.\tag{1}$$
This ensues from an application of the exponential generating function: $$\text{EG}(e^{-\lambda t}x^n,\lambda t)=\sum_nx^n\frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda t}.$$
However in Jeanblanc, Yor & Chesney (2009), Eq. (8.2.1), it is stated that the equality $(1)$ is only applicable for the case $x>0$.
Is the expectation $(1)$ only defined for $x>0$, and if so why?

The expectation is defined for  $z\in\mathbb Z$ but it may not have a nice formula.

@KurtG. why can we not use formula $(1)$ for the case $x\leq0$?

I was stupid. Since $n\in\mathbb N$ the power $x^n$ is defined for all
$x\in\mathbb R,.$ In particular, for all $x\in\mathbb Z,,$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\big[x^{N_t}\big]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda t}=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x\lambda t)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda t}=e^{\lambda t(x-1)},.
\end{align}

To be precise: this expectation formula holds for all $x\in\mathbb R,.$
